# Python Error object() takes no parameters

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 file Python: 
Pet.py

```
class Pet(object):
 def __int__(self, name, species):
  self.name = name
  self.species = species

 def getName(self):
  return self.name

 def getSpecies(self):
  return self.species

 def __str__(self):
  return "%s is %s" % (self.name, self.species)
```

And file petobject.py

```
from Pet import Pet
polly = Pet("Polly", "Parrot")
print "Polly is a %s" % polly.getSpecies()
```

When I run petobject.py I got this error : object() takes no parameters.
Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your class init function is spelled wrongly, this should be `__init__` instead of `__int__`:

```
def __init__(self, name, species):
```

Comment: Thanks very muchhhh. You've save my days.